# Error when defining mchecker for Google Play licensing

Tags: android

I got my new laptop today, and copied my eclipse workspace to it.

However, everything is working like it was except the fact that this line of code now creates an error:

```
mChecker = new LicenseChecker(
            this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
                new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
            BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY  // Your public licensing key.
            );
```

everything after the = sign is red underlined, the error stated is this:

> The constructor LicenseChecker(LicenseCheck, ServerManagedPolicy, String) is undefined

The entire code worked perfectly before I switched - and I have not changed anything, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to an import error - when I switched, the libraries were not linked correctly.

I readded everything, and then I just imported:

`import com.google.android.vending.licensing.*;`

and the issue was fixed.